# Rows not being appended correctly in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe, web-scraping

I am currently trying to scrape data from the research database - ScienceDirect. I am obtaining the title of each research article using Beautiful Soup and adding it to an empty pandas dataframe. Following this, I obtain information on the type of research article for above articles. However, when I try to append this data to the dataframe, it is being added to the bottom ie. Instead of being added to the first 100 rows, it is creating 100 new rows.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(requests.get(browser.current_url).text,"html.parser")

# Using soup to retrieve the elements related to Title, Type of Article, Names of Authors and Abstract
elements = soup.find_all("div", {"class","result-item-content"})

data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Abstract","Journal & Dates","Names of Authors","Title","Type of Article"])

for element in elements:
    atag = element.find('a')
    if atag:
        atag = atag.text.split("\n")
        data = data.append({"Title": atag}, ignore_index=True)

data.head()

Abstract    Journal & Dates Names of Authors    Title   Type of Article
0   NaN NaN NaN [Morphological, molecular identification and p...   NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN [Assessment of soil erosion in a tropical moun...   NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN [Ethnomedicinal assessment of Irula tribes of ...   NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN [Latitudinal variation in summer monsoon rainf...   NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN [IUCN greatly underestimates threat levels of ...   NaN
```

Now, I try to search for information on the Type of Research Article and I append it to the above dataframe.

```
for element in elements:
    art_type = element.find("ol",{"class","OpenAccessArchive hor"})
    if art_type:
        art_type = art_type.text.split("\n")
        data = data.append({"Type of Article": art_type}, ignore_index=True)

data.tail()

    Abstract    Journal & Dates Names of Authors    Title   Type of Article
194 NaN NaN NaN NaN [Open access, Research article, ]
195 NaN NaN NaN NaN [Research article, ]
196 NaN NaN NaN NaN [Research article, ]
197 NaN NaN NaN NaN [Research article, ]
198 NaN NaN NaN NaN [Research article, ]
```

If you look at the tail of the dataframe, weirdly, it is adding the info to the last 100 or 90 rows. How do I correct this?

Also, I am new to scraping and python. Any suggestions on what would be best way to store the data, so that I can carry out analysis on the same later? Such as a probabilistic modeling of topics?

**EDIT** based on the answer, I tried the following, but I am getting an error:

```
data_dict = {}

# Create keys
for key in ["Abstract","Journal & Dates","Names of Authors","Title","Type of Article"]:
    data_dict[key] = []

# Loop through the elements object
for element in elements:

    # Find all the Title tags
    atag = element.find('a')
    if atag:
        atag = atag.text.split("\n")
        data_dict["Title"].append(atag)

    # Find all article_type information
    art_type = element.find("ol",{"class","OpenAccessArchive hor"})
    if art_type:
        art_type = art_type.text.split("\n")
        data_dict["Type of Article"].append(art_type)

    # Find Names of Authors
    author = element.find("ol",{"class","Authors hor undefined"})
    if author:
        author = author.text.split("\n")
        data_dict["Names of Authors"].append(author)

    # Find Journal Name
    journal = element.find("ol",{"class","SubType hor"})
    if journal:
        journal = journal.text.split("\n")
        data_dict["Journal & Dates"].append(journal)

data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

*ERROR*
~/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in extract_index(data)
   6209             lengths = list(set(raw_lengths))
   6210             if len(lengths) > 1:
-> 6211                 raise ValueError('arrays must all be same length')
   6212 
   6213             if have_dicts:
```

ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: `.append` is used to append the dataframe - by definition *add* new rows - that's why data you're trying to *insert* are instead attached in new rows.

Comment: What i'm not sure about is whether `art_type` is a list that fills a single row or is it, say, a list of length 5 that's meant to fill 5 rows?

Comment: Thanks @GeneBurinsky. I think art_type is a list of items that is supposed to fill a single row at a time, with multiple items such as [Review Article, Open Access] or [Research Article] or [Research Article, Open Access}. So it could be multiple items or a single item, but is supposed to fille one row at a time. Thank you for your answer. I will try it now and see if it works.

Comment: It may also be helpful to not split the string into a list. For example, simply doing `data_dict['article_type'].append(art_type.text)` would be more convenient and later you can use `panda`'s string functionality to split as you wish. I'm guessing that it would also be better in terms of memory

Comment: Oooh,ok. That's a great suggestion. And right, better in terms of memory as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, `pd.DataFrame.append` is used to append the dataframe - by definition *add* new rows - that's why data you try to insert are instead attached in new rows. You can insert data into the dataframe individually but it's not pretty. For example, you can insert with `data.loc[i,'Title'] = atag` where `i` is a row counter (ie `i=3`) *note* this also needs you to create a full-sized empty dataframe.

instead, I recommend filling a dictionary with the data first then passing the dictionary to `pandas`; ie:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import numpy as np


#fetch data
sample_url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/search/advanced?qs=Climate%20Change&articleTypes=REV%2CFLA&show=100&sortBy=relevance"
soup = bs(requests.get(sample_url).text,"html.parser")
elements = soup.find_all("div", {"class","result-item-content"})

#create data container
data_dict = {}
for key in ["Title","Type of Article","Names of Authors","Journal & Dates"]:
    data_dict[key] = []
    #fields yet to add: "Abstract"

#convenience function:
def add_item(item,key,data_dict):
    #if item is found, add to data
    if item is not None:
        data_dict[key].append(item.text)
    #if nothing is found, add missing flag
    if item is None:
        data_dict[key].append(np.nan)

#loop over elements    
for element in elements:
    #find element
    art_type = element.find("ol",{"class","OpenAccessArchive hor"})
    add_item(art_type, "Type of Article", data_dict)

    #repeat for remainder of fields    
    atag = element.find('a')
    add_item(atag, 'Title', data_dict)

    author = element.find("ol",{"class","Authors hor undefined"})
    add_item(author, 'Names of Authors', data_dict)

    # Find Journal Name
    journal = element.find("ol",{"class","SubType hor"})
    add_item(journal,'Journal & Dates', data_dict)

data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

The sample output:

```
In [21]: data.head(n=3)
Out[21]:
                                     Journal & Dates  \
0  Global Environmental Change, Volume 50, May 20...
1  International Journal of Hygiene and Environme...
2  Global Environmental Change, Volume 50, May 20...

                                    Names of Authors  \
0  [K.M. Findlater, S.D. Donner, T. Satterfield, ...
1                                [Shouro Dasgupta, ]
2                    [Thad Kousser, Bruce Tranter, ]

                                               Title     Type of Article
0  Integration anxiety: The cognitive isolation o...  Research article,
1      Burden of climate change on malaria mortality  Research article,
2  The influence of political leaders on climate ...  Research article
```

Also note that there are missing values. I'd look into them...

```
In [37]: data.isnull().sum()
Out[37]:
Journal & Dates      0
Names of Authors    15
Title                0
Type of Article      0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but I am still getting an error since it raises an array must be the same length issue.

Comment: Further, I tried your comment on `data_dict["Type of Article"].append(art_type.text)` , but that gives me a `Nonetype object has no attribute text` error.

Comment: @VijayRamesh the second part comes because because sometimes certain tags are not found in the website. For example, if a journal doesn't have tags or types or for some reason the website is different in the backend then `element.find` will return a `Nonetype`. Because of this, you should always include error checkers. Regarding the second error, if you have 5 Abstracts but only 3 sets of authors, and 4 Titles then `pandas` won't be able to create the dataframe. Can you give a link to at least one of the websites you're scraping?

Comment: Here's a link to one of the pages I am scraping - https://www.sciencedirect.com/search/advanced?qs=Climate%20Change&articleTypes=REV%2CFLA&show=100&sortBy=relevance

Comment: @VijayRamesh thanks for the sample url. The code above should work. I forgot to add fillers for times when nothing is found. Additionally, because in the example we are only filling in `"Title"` and `'Type of Article"`, I restricted the `data_dict` to only have those fields but you add the rest of fields, you should add back the other keys.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Looks like it works, and you are right, some elements are not being scraped, because they probably have different HTML paths, which I just realized. Need to figure out an if statement to scrape either this path or the other and add it to the dictionary.